# How is it possible to trigger recaptcha v3 (score test) every time a user clicks on a submit button in contact from 7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have followed the steps in contact form 7 and its working fine but I want to trigger it automatically every time a user clicks on the submit button rather than Google judging by itself who is a bot and prompting the test for bots only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger reCaptcha on a button, you simply need to bind the captcha to a button.

```
<button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="yourKey" data-callback="onSubmit">Submit</button>
```

then add "onSubmit" function to handle reCaptcha's response.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var onSubmit = function(response) {
    document.getElementById("simpleForm").submit(); // send response to your backend service
  };
</script>
```

Reference from https://product.hubspot.com/blog/quick-guide-invisible-recaptcha